# Crop path within canvas Android

Tags: android, canvas, android-canvas

In the below image red color is the canvas. The black color part  is the figure I am drawing in my canvas. I want to crop the black color part from my canvas. How shall I do it?.

I tried using `canvas.clipPath()` but I guess its no longer supported in Android now, due to hardware acceleration. I tried disableing the hardware acceleration also but it dint work so I gave up on `canvas.clipPath()`.

Is there any other way I can use to crop path within `canvas`?

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance :)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: "crop the black color" what do. you exactly mean?

Comment: i dont want the red color part as part of my view (red color is the custom view where I am drawing)

Comment: so dont draw the red part? draw only black part

Comment: the red part is the entire canvas.

Comment: the red part is the extra space of the canvas I want to remove that

Comment: I will b adding this custom view to my acyivity so I dont want that red color (extra spcace) in my activity

Comment: @pskink i hope u understood my question ?

Comment: who draws that red color?

Comment: i have set the bg color as red just to show u guys the extra space of canvas being generated which I want to remove

Comment: @pskink basically i want to remove the extra space of my canvas after I finish drawing so that my view is exactly of the shape wat I draw

Comment: so make its dimensions to mach the black part

Comment: @pskink then the tail part wont be visible of the black fig

Comment: so i dont understand your question at all, what do you want as the output? a view? bitmap? drawable?

Comment: I just want the complete black color fig without red color as my output it doesnt have to be a view even bitmap or drawable will do

Comment: ok so what do you need it for?

Comment: I need it to place it in my activity. Where I will b having touch listener added to it so that user can move it

Comment: you cannot place a Canvas in your activity, activity has no concept of Canvas, Canvas can be attached to View or Bitmap only

Comment: Currently I am placing it in my activity as a view

Comment: The grey bg in my image above is my activity (empty) the black+red color image is my custom view. I want that red color part to b excluded from my view

Comment: so create a big custom view that covers. the whole screen and draw whatever you want in onDraw method

Comment: @pskink the red color is the bg color of the canvas. I can set it to Color.TRANSPARENT and the red color will go away. The reason I hv set it to red color is to show u guys that extra space is being generated. When I place the view in my activity and add the touch listener to it, and if user touches the extra space which transparent and not visible the touch event gets fired. I want to avoid it which is y I want to remove the extra space i.e red color in the above img

Comment: @pskink i will b having multiple views added dynamically in my activity

Comment: @pskink I think i will be approaching this prob in a diff way cud u pls ans this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22930048/adding-multiple-touch-listeners-inside-canvas-android?lq=1

Comment: did you see my answer?

Comment: @pskink yes i saw ur ans but its for two finger touch

Comment: active Layer selection has nothing to do with multitouch, it simply finds the Layer under the finger and makes it active sending any other MorionEvents to that Layer

Comment: @pskink I have added two images in my question above. The first image has two custom views added in my activity. One has red color representing its extra space and other has grey color as its extra space. In the second image the two images are overlapping, the "Orange" pointer shows wer the user is touching on screen. Since I will be setting canvas bg as transparent the red and grey color wont b visible to user. Now the user wants to move the blue circle but instead the black square will move since v are actually touching the grey part which will activate the black color square custom view

Comment: did you try my code? if you dont want scale/rotate gestures just remove them

Comment: @pskink no i havent tried it out yet. are u sure it will work in my case?

Comment: @pskink were is ur MoveGestureDetector class?

Comment: it will work, just create three .png images: circle, triangle, star and test it

Comment: @pskink okay. I got the class from the link u provided

Comment: @pskink awesome :) its working however I tried it with some imageviews I had my how can I put my custom views inside ids array ??

Comment: @pskink anyways thanks a lot man I really appreciate ur help :) can u also explain me  ur ViewPort Class and also how to put custom views instead of imageviews ??

Comment: what ImageViews? i dont use any ImageViews, i use Layer class which draws a Bitmap

Comment: i mean, int[] ids = {R.drawable.handle_move, R.drawable.handle_scale, R.drawable.ic_launcher}; here we are giving the images from res folder how can I pass my custom views which I am drawing instead of those images

Comment: Layer.draw draws a Bitmap, so you can put your custom drawing there

Comment: @pskink i am drawing my drawings on a bitmap and passing it to the ViewPort class and adding it to the Layer class and its working fine :). But one thing I dint understand is that how is it recognizing the bitmap ??? can u pls explain that. As in v have arrays of bitmaps how is it recognizing each one ?

Comment: recognizing the bitmap ??? what you mean?

Comment: as in even if the image is below another image it brings the image above and moves it. If i take my example of above two images that I hv added. If I am clicking on the grey part (which is invisible) it still brings the blue circle above and moves it.

Comment: target = l;layers.remove(l);layers.add(l);invalidate(); I knw that this code shifts the bitmaps arrangements but how is it determining the bitmap ?

Comment: the code you mentioned is executed in "if": if (l.contains(event)) {...

Comment: no wat I meant was is - how is it recognizing the blue circle if I click on the grey portion of the black box ?

Comment: I think this function is the key in identifying the bitmaps can u pls explain this func - public boolean contains(MotionEvent event) {
        matrix.invert(inverse);
        float[] pts = {event.getX(), event.getY()};
        inverse.mapPoints(pts);
        if (!bounds.contains(pts[0], pts[1])) {
            return false;
        }
        return Color.alpha(bitmap.getPixel((int) pts[0], (int) pts[1])) != 0;
    }

Comment: just debug it, place the breakpoint in the first line of contains() method, "step over" each line and see the variables